# warファイルをビルドした日時を取得したい

Tags: java, gradle, java-ee

JavaEE（ビルドはgradle）でWebアプリケーションを開発しています。
掲題通り、warファイルをビルドした日時を、アプリケーション上から取得したいです。
プロダクトの開発・テスト中に、いつビルドしたものなのかを画面上に表示することが目的です。
何か標準のAPI等で簡単に取れるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メソッド一発呼び出しなど、簡単に取得する方法はないと思います。
というのも、「いつビルドしたか」は言語と開発ではなく、ビルドのプロセスで補完される
べき情報だからです。なので、ビルド時にその情報を埋め込む必要があります。

一案としては、

ビルド時に、build.propertiesを作成、builddate=yyyy.mm.ddとしてWEB-INF/classesあたりのクラスローダにのるディレクトリに埋め込んでおく。
クラスローダから、以下のようなコードでpropertyを取得
`ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("build.properties");`
(実際には取得できるinsputstreamを使って、Properies#loadすることで、Poperiesオブジェクトを取得します。）